# How to access classes defined under Java Resources in JSP Pages

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am a newbie in JAVA and currently exploring Servlet and JSP. 
In my Servlet class,  I am adding a new property to request and accessing the same in JSP via request.getSession().getAttribute("schoolschedule"). However to "schoolschedule", I am passing  an object and I am not able to reach to the methods of the object of schoolschedule.
I tried importing the class via:
<@page import="class-name" %> but kept getting cannot resolve error.
It might be a very stupid question to begin with but since I am newbie I just want to explore.

Comment: I think you need a servlet to add to the session on the server side.  Here's a question: JSPs are a 1999 vintage technology, Sun's answer to Active Server Pages.  The world has moved on to HTML5, CSS3, and REST services.  Why are you stuck in 1999?

Comment: Take a look at some [tutorials](http://programmergate.com/pass-data-servlet-jsp/).    JSP's may not be quite as out of date @duffymo suggested but there are better long term solutions.  If you're just learning that's fine but you'll need to continue your learning after JSP's.

Comment: If you do decide to pursue JSPs, please discard any tutorial that includes scriptlet code.  Do not, under any circumstance, waste any time learning to inject scriptlet code into JSPs.  Learn the JSP Standard Template Library if you must persist in this direction.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advise. I am a seasoned JS developer, learing Java these days. Wanted to start from the basics so that I can really appreciate the latest development.